# Can I save data with relational table at a time in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables Lead and **Comment**. The relation is given below:

```
 public function comments(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
```

**Working Code:**

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($lead, $comment) {
            $lead->save();
            $lead->comments()->save($comment);
        });
```

> **But, my question is can I do it in a single line code, means only one save method?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the push method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-push-method) to recursively save the model object and its relationship. So you might want to do something like:

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($lead, $comment) {
    $lead->fill([
        //some attributes to be updated.
    ]);
    $comment->fill(['lead_id' => $lead->id]);
    $lead->push();
});
```